# Passing Html.DropdownListFor values to other view on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an small booking system in MVC. Right now I have created an model **(BookingViewModel)** an controller **(BookingController)** and a view which contains dropdownlists and a button.

The user is going to go over a number of steps (Views) in order to complete the booking. The index view from the BookingController is the first step.

So the next step is **Seat** (Where the user can point on a seat he wants to sit). Here i thinking of createing another controller and also make an Index view. How do i get the values from the first index view to this step?

I know that I should use the Httppost method, but right now i'm getting an error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'DepartureRoute' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

So based on the values you enter on the first step, I want to use these values in the next step so I can search the database.

**BookingController**

```
namespace BookingMvc.Controllers
{
public class BookingController : Controller
{
    // GET: Booking
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new BookingViewModel();

        var citiesList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Oslo to Copenhagen" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Copenhagen to Oslo" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Copenhagen to Stockholm" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Stockholm to Copenhagen" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Oslo to Stockholm" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Stockholm to Oslo" },
    };

        var numberList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "0" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2"}
    };

        vm.Cities = citiesList;
        vm.Number = numberList;

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BookingViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
            return View(vm);   
    }

}
}
```

**BookingViewModel**

```
namespace BookingMvc.Models
{
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public string departureroute { get; set; }
    public string returnroute { get; set; }
    public DateTime departuredate { get; set; }
    public DateTime returndate { get; set; }
    public int adults { get; set; }
    public int childrens { get; set; }

    //Enum lists
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Number { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Step 1 "Index View"**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.Label("Outgoing route") <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.departureroute, Model.Cities, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })

    <br />

    @Html.Label("Departure date") <br />
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })
    </div>


    <br />

    @Html.Label("Adult") <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.adults, Model.Number, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.Label("Return route") <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.returnroute, Model.Cities, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })

    <br />

    @Html.Label("Return date") <br />
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })

    </div>

    <br />

    @Html.Label("Children") <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.childrens, Model.Number, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="bookinginfomation">
        @Html.Label("Booking information") <br />
        <button type="submit" class="bookingbutton">Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Hope someone can tell me what i should look at in order to get values to the next step (view)

Comment: In your POST method you have `return View(vm)` but you do not repopulate the `Model.Cities` select list so its `null`. Because its `null` the fallback of the `DropDownListFor()` method is that `departureroute` must be `IEnumerable<T>`, but its not (its `string`), hence the error

Comment: So what will you recommend me to do?

Comment: Before the line `return View(vm);` you need to repopulate the `SelectList`'s - just as you did in the GET method which will prevent that error. But there are multiple other errors in you code anyway for example you have 2 `@Html.TextBox("Name", ..)` which are generating controls that have no relationship to your model (and generating invalid html). Your creating `<label>` elements which are not labels (clicking on them will not set focus to the associated control)